# How to organize authorized react routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How do you organize index routes properly if you either redirect or show landing page? This looks messy:

```
<Switch>
    <Route
      path="/"
      exact
      render={() => (!isLogged ? <Landing /> : <Redirect to="/dashboard" />)}
    />
```

You could also wrap it in if-else statements.

```
if (!isLogged) {  
   routes = (
   <Route path="/" component={Landing} />
     ....
  )  
} else {
 routes = (
  <Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/dashboard"} />
  .....
  )
}
```

but this feels messy as well... any solutions out there?

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use a wrapper component which returns a `<Route />` if the user is logged in, or the landing component if not.

```
const LoggedInRoute = (props) => {
   if(!isLoggedIn) {
      return <Landing />
   }
   return <Route {...props} />
}
```

Usage:

```
<LoggedInRoute 
   path="/"
   exact
   render={() => <Redirect to="/dashboard" />}
 />
```